# Java: Не видит конструктор, или как сделать правильный импорт?

Tags: java, ооп, javafx, импорт, инкапсуляция

Такая проблема, есть пакет `A` и подпакет `A.b` 
в пакете `A` есть класс `Class1`, А в пакете `A.b` класс `Сlass2` 
Так вот, если я делаю `import A.Class1;` в классе `Сlass2`
То при создании экземпляра вложенного класса `Class3` который есть в `Class1` бросает ошибку:

> no suitable constructor found for Class3(String,String)

Хотя такой конструктор есть 100%. И самое главное если же перетащить класс С2 в пакет A то все работает отлично. 
Я не понимаю по какой причине так. Возможно мало подробностей дал, жду в комментариях если что то необходимо еще 
**UPD:** Возможно стоит заметить что это все делается в javafx, а класс `С2` представляет из себя контроллер fxml док-а

Comment: Вложенный класс C3 публичный и статический?

Comment: @АлександрПоташев Да, все именно так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась тем что конструкторы вложенного класса `Class3` должны были быть `public`, в то время как у меня, все было без какого либо модификатора доступа.